# Data Manipulation Row_Number() SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need some guidance and help with a data manipulation question in SQL SERVER 2012.

This is how my data looks like:

```
=================================================
YearMonth LocationCode  New     ValidTo
=================================================
201412         2020     1       201502
201501        2020      1       201503
201503        3030      1       201506
201506        3030      1       201509
```

***Problem description***

if you look at the above table, you will see the column `YearMonth` , `locationCode`, `New` which tells whether the `locationCode` is new for the month in the row. The ValidTo column shows to which `ValidTo` `YearMonth` it is validto.

For the example, for `YearMonth` 201412, the `locationCode` 2020 is 1, which means here it is `New` and that `LocationCode` is considered New till `ValidTo` 201502.

My  problem is that I need to make each LocationCode , that appears in the earliest YearMonth Column, to New, is this case "1" till the ValidTo YearMonth.

**Objective:**

```
=================================================
YearMonth LocationCode  New     ValidTo
=================================================
201412         2020     1       201502
201501        2020      1       201503
201503        3030      1       201506
201506        3030      0       201509
```

Basically, I need to find out the `MIN()` for each `LocationCode` and then categorize it as `NEW`,"1" and if the `LocationCode` appears within the MIN() `YearMonth` and `ValidTo` then categorize the `LocationCode` in `New` as "1".

How Can I do that? The above table provides a visual example.

I have edited my final table to make it simpler to understand my question.

Basically,the `MIN() Year` for `LocationCode` 3030 is 201503 and the `LocationCode` is valid till 201506 as demostrated in the `Validto` Column. If the `LocationCode` 3030 were to appear in the `YearMonth` row, 201505 with a `VALIDTO` till 201506, then we classify it as `New`(1) as well.

Basically,pseudocode

```
SELECT

MIN(YearMonth),
LocationCode

from Tabl
```

If `LocationCode` , is in MIN(YearMonth) AND `ValidTO` timeperiod then classify it as 1. How can I do this?

Comment: The LocationCodes in the Objective seems to be wrong (they are all 2020, but in the initial data they are 2020 and 3030)

Comment: And I'm not even sure of the second ValidTo of objective (201502)

Comment: In my second table, as you can see, the LocationCode appears in multiple yearMonths.I am showing an example how the final product I am trying to produce.

Comment: Xantos, the table in beneath the Objective heading, is what I am trying to produce. The first table is an overall data structure of the table.

Comment: So for your example, you want all the location codes that fall between 201412 and 201502 to be marked as new?

Comment: What is the logic behind changing all the LocationCodes to 2020?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below query for updating the table:
The inner most query calculates the minimum `Yearmonth` per `LocationCode` which is used to calculate all `ValidTo` and `LocationCode`s which need to be updated to 1 in `ValidTo` column

```
update t2
set New= CASE when t1.ValidTo is null then 0 else 1 end 
FROM tbl t2
LEFT JOIN 
(
  select t.ValidTo, t.locationCode 
       from tbl t inner join
           (
             select 
                MIN(YearMonth) as MYM, 
                LocationCode 
             from tbl
               group by LocationCode
            ) g 
       on t.YearMonth=g.MYM and t.LocationCode=g.LocationCode
) t1
on t2.ValidTo=t1.ValidTo and t2.LocationCode=t1.LocationCode
```

sample sql fiddle for demo:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/229d8